# "ValueError: _bcrypt.crypt_rn returned None" using cryptacular.bcrypt under pyenv installed python on Fedora

Tags: python, fedora, pyenv

Quite a specific issue - only seen when running **python** (3.9.7, 3.8.12) installed with **pyenv** on **Fedora** (34).

Using the system installed python (3.9.7) the error is not seen. As such I'm not sure whether this is a pyenv issue, or a cryptacular one.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install pyenv as per the [instructions](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation) (first the build dependencies, then pyenv, then set the shell's environment)
2. Install python 3.9.7 using pyenv, and set as global python version:

   ```
   $ pyenv install 3.9.7
   $ pyenv global 3.9.7
   ```
3. Create virtualenv, and install cryptacular (1.6.2 at time of writing)

   ```
   $ python -m venv venv
   $ ./venv/bin/pip install cryptacular
   ```
4. Create `minimal.py` with example for triggering the error:

   ```py
   from cryptacular.bcrypt import BCRYPTPasswordManager

   pm = BCRYPTPasswordManager()
   print(pm.encode("Password123!"))
   ```
5. Run example code and observe error:

   ```
   $ ./venv/bin/python minimal.py
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/home/vagrant/minimal.py", line 4, in <module>
       pm.encode("Password123!")
     File "/home/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cryptacular/bcrypt/__init__.py", line 54, in encode
       raise ValueError("_bcrypt.crypt_rn returned None")
   ValueError: _bcrypt.crypt_rn returned None
   ```
6. Complete the same steps using the system python (also 3.9.7), and error is not triggered:

   ```
   $ rm -rf venv
   $ pyenv global system
   $ python -m venv venv
   $ ./venv/bin/pip install cryptacular
   ...
   ...
   $ ./venv/bin/python minimal.py
   $2a$10$mWRafuCTZq.OIZEt5CDln.LFWrj9qFnbjjhIHWL6pXZU4TU/tPm0K
   ```

I'm not really even sure where to start looking into this error, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @pxul, could you have a look at this link and see if it helps? I experienced an issue with Fedora shipping with libcrypt 2 but packages needing libcrypt 1. Installing libxcrypt-compat resolved the issue: https://serverfault.com/a/1019847